# How to combine tables in python 3

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I am trying to combine all the reports tables that I have into one big table. It will have one row per country-city per day.

I'm using Anaconda Navigator and I lunch Jupyter notebook and their tables will be uploaded

***Example of the data:***

reports table

[Reports table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yd9N.png)

[Reports table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYrjL.png)

[Reports table 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWfWb.png)

***Code:***

```
rom datascience import *
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plots
plots.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

DR1 = Table.read_table('01-22-2020.csv')
DR2 = Table.read_table('01-23-2020.csv')
DR3 = Table.read_table('01-24-2020.csv')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Comment: @KlausD. ok I just uploaded it

Comment: Add your code to the question as code-formatted text. Links and screenshots can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @KlausD.  ok I changed it